# Simplification of rational expressions

Tags: maxima

I'm struggling with getting maxima to simplify expressions in the way that I want them.

```
rhs(solve(a*x-3=b*y,x)[1]);
```

returns

```
(b*y+3)/3
```

However, I'm wanting to display the result to students and so I want the output to be

```
(b*y/3) + 1
```

Is there some simplification that I can do to a rational expression in this form to get the output I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can undo the effect of `ratsimp` in this case by dividing each term in the numerator by the denominator. Here is a simple-minded implementation:

```
(%i1) unratsimp (e) := 
          block ([foo, bar],
                 [foo, bar]: [num(e), denom(e)],
                 map (lambda ([foo1], foo1/bar), expand (foo))) $
(%i2) 1 + a/b + c*d/3 - %pi*x/y;
                        %pi x    c d   a
(%o2)                (- -----) + --- + - + 1
                          y       3    b
(%i3) ratsimp(%);
                (b c d + 3 b + 3 a) y - 3 %pi b x
(%o3)           ---------------------------------
                              3 b y
(%i4) unratsimp(%);
                        %pi x    c d   a
(%o4)                (- -----) + --- + - + 1
                          y       3    b
(%i5) unratsimp((b*y + 3)/3);
                             b y
(%o5)                        --- + 1
                              3
```

I don't know how general that is; it's just the first thing I tried, but maybe it's enough for your purpose. I don't know a built-in function for this.

The results %o4 and %o5 are maybe not exactly as a human would write them. Convincing Maxima to display the terms in `+` and `*` expressions in a different way is not straightforward -- Maxima has strong ideas about how to order terms in an expression which are assumed throughout the code. But I think that others have asked questions, which might have answers, about displaying expressions -- you might search Stackoverflow if you are are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The command you can use here is `multthru`:

```
(%i1) e1:(b*y+3)/3;
(%o1) (b*y+3)/3
(%i2) multthru(e1);
(%o2) (b*y)/3+1
```

In this case also the following will work

```
(%i3) distrib(e1);
(%o3) (b*y)/3+1
(%i4) expand(e1);
(%o4) (b*y)/3+1
```